# Trouble linking a mex file to static mpfr library

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, static-linking, mex

I am trying to compile a mex file that requires the mpfr C library, using MATLAB R2013a on Mac OS 10.8.5.  I would like it to run on systems that don't have a separate installation of MPFR, so I am trying to include the static library:

```
mex my_program.c libmpfr.a
```

I copied the libmpfr.a library into the folder with my source code to simplify things.  When I run this command I get the following error message:

```
ld: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables in _mpfr_add for architecture x86_64
```

A little research suggested that this issue could be due to a problem with the llvm-gcc-4.2 compiler that comes with Xcode and is used in MATLAB by default. So, I tried to set up a different compiler.  I got GCC 4.7.4 (the latest version supported by MATLAB) from MacPorts, as described here: http://www.ficksworkshop.com/blog/14-coding/65-installing-gcc-on-mac.  Next, I edited the mexopts.sh file to point MATLAB to the correct compiler, by entering the following settings:

```
CC='/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7'
CXX='/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.7'
```

Now when I try to compile, I get a different error message:

```
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:294:0,
             from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
             from include/main.h:5,
             from include/poisson.h:7,
             from src/main.c:22:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:61:21: fatal error: float.h: No such file or directory
```

If, in mexopts.sh, I additionally set

```
SDKROOT='/opt/local/'
```

or a number of other choices (based on the locations of different copies of float.h that I can find on my system), I instead see

```
my_program.c:10:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

So it seems that GCC-MP-4.7 is having trouble locating all of the standard C libraries.

I'd be grateful for a solution to either of these issues (linking to static mpfr useing the default compiler, or configuring GCC 4.7 to find the standard C libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "thread local variables" error was caused by the compiler trying to include backwards-compatibility to OSX 10.5.  Since I don't need it to do this, I edited the mexopts.sh file, replacing this line

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.5'
```

with this:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8'
```

This resulted in the mex file compiling successfully using the built-in Xcode compiler.